# How do I check if a template parameter is a power of two?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, constexpr, static-assert

I want to create a structure that allocates statically an array of **2^N bytes**, but I don't want the users of this structure to specify this size as the exponent. Example:

```
my_stupid_array<char, 32> a1; // I want this!
my_stupid_array<char, 5> a2; // And not this...
```

How do I check if this template parameter is a power of two **and** warn the user with a nice message about this?

I've been able to check for this with a simple template:

```
template<int N>
struct is_power_of_two {
    enum {val = (N >= 1) & !(N & (N - 1))};
};
```

However, I'm unable to warn the user about this with a sane message. Any ideas?

**EDIT**

Fixed the ambiguous example.

**EDIT**

1 is a power of two indeed. Fixed that! :)

**EDIT**

Using BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT, I'm getting this compile error for this code with GCC:

```
template<int N>
struct is_power_of_two {
    enum {val = (N >= 1) & !(N & (N - 1))};
    BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT(val);
};
```

Error

```
..\main.cpp:29:1: error: invalid application of 'sizeof' to incomplete type 'boost::STATIC_ASSERTION_FAILURE<false>'
```

[http://ideone.com/cMfEf](http://ideone.com/kyMJ8)

**EDIT**

Oh, I get it. That was the message that I'm supposed to get when the assert fails. But that fails to give the user some sane message. :(

Comment: 8 is a power of 2...

Comment: It's meant as an example of exponent as parameter. 2^8 = 256

Comment: >`my_stupid_array<char, 8> a2; // And not this...` why not this?

Comment: @jrok: I realise that, but the point remains...

Comment: @triclosan It could be that way, but it's not intuitive and as I'm not in such a hurry I thought I could ask and learn something new. :)

Comment: @haole: The example might have been ambiguous, but it exposed a flaw in what you're trying to do...

Comment: Did you mean `(N >= 1) & !(N & (N - 1))`?  The number 1 is a power of two, after all.

Comment: The compile error for argument value 5 is correct. It's not a power of 2 so the static_assert gives a compile-error (where the usual assert gives a run-time error).

Comment: Write a sane message in the documentation instead of trying to get a sane error message from the compiler.

Comment: @VJovic sure, but you got to admit that static_assert with a custom message is very cool! :)

Comment: Yes, it's great they added it

Answer (score 30, accepted):

These days, with `constexpr` and the [bit twiddling hacks](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#DetermineIfPowerOf2) you can just

```
constexpr bool is_powerof2(int v) {
    return v && ((v & (v - 1)) == 0);
}
```

Comment: This is the real solution.

Answer (score 24):

static_assert to the rescue (C++11 only, uncomment BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT for C++03):

```
#include<iostream>
// #include <boost/static_assert.hpp>

template<int N>
struct is_power_of_two {
    enum {val = N && !(N & (N - 1))};
    static_assert(val, "should use a power of 2 as template parameter");
    // BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT(val); // without C++11 support, won't take a string message
};

int main()
{
        std::cout << is_power_of_two<2>::val << "\n";
        std::cout << is_power_of_two<3>::val << "\n";
}
```

[Ideone output for C++11](http://ideone.com/M8K7a)

[Ideone output for C++03](http://ideone.com/sONFF)

**UPDATE1**: other idea (I know you don't want this, but it is a lot easier for large exponents):

```
template<int N>
make_power_of_two
{
    enum { val = 1 << N };
};

my_stupid_array<char, make_power_of_two<5>::val > a1; // size 2^5 = 32
```

**UPDATE2**: based on comments by @sehe in the chat, you can do this for `constexpr` functions as well

```
constexpr bool is_power_of_two(int x)
{
    return x && ((x & (x-1)) == 0);
}
```

Comment: Beat me to it. Might as well mention BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT for C++03.

Comment: Damnit. Was just about to give [this link](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/boost_staticassert.html). I have to learn to type faster.

Comment: My embedded compiler won't do C++11 yet. I'll try the boost alternative and add this to the answer if it works.

Comment: Very nice... Although strictly speaking 1 *is* a power of 2.  :-)

Comment: BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT accepts only one parameter. Also, I'm getting a compile error that I'm trying to figure it out. Gonna update the question.

Comment: @haole Updated the answer with Ideone output for BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT for C++03 compilers. The BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT_MSG variant takes a string message as well, but this only works for C++11. Note that the compile-time erorr is correct! (This is what static asserts do...)

Comment: What you can always do with `BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT` to include a message is this: `BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT(val && "This is SO wrong!")`. (For those who wonder: a string literal in a boolean context evaluates the pointer to the literal which is always non-zero, i.e. true)

Comment: @ArneMertz thanks yes, that is the same as with regular `assert(cond && "message")`. I guess I should have phrased it slightly differently, since my main point was that `static_assert` requires a message (can be "", but still annoying to type).

Answer (score 12):

You can use `static_assert` to provide an error message:

```
template<int N>
struct is_power_of_two {
    static_assert((N > 1) & !(N & (N - 1)), "Template parameter must be a power of two.");
};
```

Comment: +1 More bit twiddling hacks here: http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#DetermineIfPowerOf2. Posted my own version based on `constexpr` :/

Comment: N > 1 should be N > 0, since 1 is 2^0.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but I'd like to throw in another option I've just used based on the above answers (thank you btw!) with c++20 concepts:

```cpp
template<auto V>
constexpr bool is_power_of_two = V && ((V & (V - 1)) == 0);


template<class T, auto SIZE> requires is_power_of_two<SIZE>
using my_stupid_array = std::array<T, SIZE>;


my_stupid_array<char, 32> a1;  // FINE
my_stupid_array<char, 5> a1;   // COMPILER ERROR
```